# Subsetting Data using a Sliding Window Approach

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame that is 640 rows by 50,000 columns.

My goal is to take the first 200 columns and step by 100 columns to extract data up to the 50,000 column for further analysis.

Example:

Data set 1: [640, 1:200]

Data set 2: [640, 100:300]

This repeats until 50,000 columns

Comment: Just generate all the starting points 1, 100, 200 ... 50,000 and then subset the data. For generating the starting point you may use for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example taking 4 columns at a time of the builtin anscombe data frame advancing by 2 columns at each iteration.   For purposes of example the processing here is just to sum all data in the columns under consideration at the current iteration. It will invoke the anonymous function with arguments 1:4, 3:6 and 5:8.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(1:ncol(anscombe), 4, by = 2, function(ix) sum(anscombe[, ix]))
```